# In Nginx how to assign cache control response header

Tags: nginx

Based on the response code I would like to set the cache control header in map if it is 301 the set "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" else default set the value which came with the response. Is there a response_cache_controle or similar command

```
map $status $bb2_cache_control_header {
    301    "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    default $response_cache_control";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) directive as follow:

```
add_header Cache-Control $bb2_cache_control_header;
```